# Things to consider before changing hosting server

Tags: web-hosting, transfer

I would like to know what things we should consider before changing our hosting server.

i.e Suppose my source website is being hosted in specific IP of other people/provider. I do have username and password to access its cpanel.

I would like to transfer it to my own hosting server with a different IP. I have a username and password to access that cpanel too.

**Now what are the things to be consider before changing the hosting server?**

Comment: I notice you always link to your domain in your questions to SO & SE. You should know that the links are nofollowed, so this technique won't work to get backlinks/reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Cpanel allows you to do a "full" backup, as it says on my version, 11.28.87-RELEASE_51188:

> A full backup includes all of the
>   files in your home directory, your
>   MySQL Databases, and your email
>   forwarders and filters. You can backup
>   your account to preserve your data or
>   use a backup file to move your account
>   to another cPanel server.

However it's probably worth going through all the screens to see what you've got configured as that doesn't seem to include all your settings, such as cron jobs.

Comment: can we use that backup to restore in new hosting server and make it same as the old one?

Comment: Yes, but watch out if the cPanel versions are a long way apart, as the backup data format may have changed. You may still need to set up the other things that I mentioned when I said "go through all the screens".